# Xamarin Forms - Can't Override Style With TextColor Property

Tags: user-interface, xamarin, overriding, xamarin.forms

I have a label style defined like:

```
var myLabelStyle = new Style(typeof(Label))
{
    Setters =
    {
        new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Blue },
        new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 30 }
    }
};
```

Then I have a label defined like this:

```
var myLabel = new Label
{
    Text = "My Label",
    Style = myLabelStyle,
    TextColor = Color.Red
};
```

Shouldn't the color of that label be Red? Well, it's blue.

I should be able to override any given property defined in a Style, according to intuition and [Xamarin docs](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/explicit/) (see the single sentence after the screenshot).

What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be a **Xamarin Forms bug** introduced somewhere between Version 2.0.0.6482 (works as expected) and **Version 2.2.0.31** (broken! does not work as expected).

Comment: I never found one, except to revert back to the older version of Xamarin Forms (unless they fixed it in a newer version).

Comment: I've been forced to create a bunch of extra styles. Thanks for getting back.

Answer (score 0):

I do not see anything wrong with your code:, it is working in this example:

```
var myLabelStyle = new Style(typeof(Label))
{
    Setters =
    {
    new Setter { Property = Label.TextColorProperty, Value = Color.Blue },
    new Setter { Property = Label.FontSizeProperty, Value = 30 }
    }
};
var myLabelRed = new Label
{
    Text = "My Red Label",
    Style = myLabelStyle,
    TextColor = Color.Red
};
var myLabelBlue = new Label
{
    Text = "My Blue Label",
    Style = myLabelStyle,
};
var content = new ContentPage
{
    Content = new StackLayout
    {
        Children = {
            myLabelRed,
            myLabelBlue
        }
    }
};
```

iOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Comment: If I create a new project, it works as expected, but it doesn't work in the project I'm in. It does work in my current project if I put my code directly in App.cs and then call  `MainPage = new ContentPage { Content = new StackLayout { Children = { myLabel } } }`. But if I create a new MyPage.cs that inherits from ContentPage, put my code in there, and then in App.cs call `MainPage = new MyPage()`, it doesn't work. I am using Fody.PropertyChanged, and I'm starting to wonder if that's the issue.

Comment: This is b/c the new project was using a version of Xamarin Forms in which this is not broken.